# HTTPS only login screen for MVC 3 application in IIS 6.0

Tags: http, iis, https

I have my MVC 3 application deployed in IIS 6.0. I need to setup https only for login page and other pages in http. I checked the Require SSL checkbox in IIS but this setting makes all my pages as https. Do i need to congifure something else in IIS to make this work ?